# How to REST call Angular TypeScript Server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, http

I am currently working on a Sessions Server for a company project.

My problem is, I cant find any help to accomplish, that I can do javascript HTTP calls from a javascript server running with `http.createServer()` and `server.listen(8080, ...)` to my Angular Server, which is hosted with `ng serve` running on `localhost:4200`.

What I want, respectively need,is something like mentioned below in pseudocode:

In my Angular TypeScript file I need something like:

```
    private listdata = new Array<string>();

    ngOnInit(){}

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
       this.http.listen(method: "POST", address: "http://localhost:4200/data", callback: => (data){
           this.listdata = data;}
       )
    }
```

So that my Angular Application (Server) can receive REST calls from another Server.

In my JavaScript file I want to do smth. like:

```
http.post("localhost:4200/data", data, httpOptions);
```

So in the end, my javascript server running on `localhost:8080` sends data to my angular server running on `localhost:4200`.

I tried to read me through several sources, containing HttpInterceptors etc. but couldnt find a simple solution for Noobs like me.

Is there an easy way, so that my automatically builded and hosted Angular Server can define routes it listens to and process the data directly for frontend use?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe this article is of help: https://itnext.io/server-side-typescript-with-node-c5cef1584684

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I couldnt find what I need. I want to edit my Angular server, started by ng serve, do you know where I can define the listener?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you have to read documentation again
2. In my opinion or am using like that when calling rest.

2.1 Rest function have to write in httpService.service.ts

2.2 Rest I used to HttpInterceptor to login OAUTH it will check auth guards,
then token expired you check easy way.
3. last question: You asking like roles something, you want to show components different users? yes you can manage routing,

https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-to-integrate-interceptor-in-angular-9/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try to fix my problem with an Inteceptor and come back if it didnt help.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt help, I guess there is no way to let my Angular server listen to requests, like an Express server could.